# Proof that state-based (convergent) CRDTs are causally-consistent

Tags: data-structures, distributed-systems, consistency-model

Conflict-Free Replicated Datatypes (CRDTs) are a class of distributed data structures where replica states are allowed to temporarily diverge, but will eventually converge (in the absence of network partitions). [2](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00555588/document)

Specifically, the class of CRDTs known as *state-based* (or *convergent*) achieved the above by requiring the data structure state to be drawn from a (semi)lattice (thus drawing on properties of least upper bound to achieve convergence).

Causal consistency is a consistency model where events/operations are applied in an order that is consistent with Lamport's *happens-before* relation. [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_consistency)

**Is there a formal proof that state-based CRDTs are, by construction, causally consistent?**

This is hinted at in this paper [4](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00934311), but without a full proof (or a full theorem statement, for that matter):

[image: paper screenshot]